# What confidence intervals is visreg producing for lmer model?

Tags: r, lme4

According to latest information in help files and on GitHub, visreg should not produce confidence intervals for conditional plots on merMod objects produced by lmer.  However, it does produce confidence intervals.  should I trust them?

I have researched all help materials and GitHub discussion from the author:
http://pbreheny.github.io/visreg/mixed.html

Using the same code used by the author:

```
fit <- lmer(protein ~ Diet + Time + (Time|Cow), Milk)

visreg(fit, "Diet")
```

I expect no confidence intervals, but my plots show confidence intervals.
Since they are not described by the package author, and are not SUPPOSED to appear, can i trust them?

Comment: When I run the code in the vignette I don't get confidence intervals.  Are you using a current version of the package?  I just updated to 2.5-0.

Comment: Apologies for a rookie mistake, this does not happen in a clean workspace, even when I load all the same packages in the same order. It is unclear to me how this is happening, but i do get confidence intervals in my workspace. I will opt not to trust them, and use confidence intervals suggested by Ben Bolker and plot them outside of the visreg package. Thanks for your interest!